# how to test jquery autocomplete in rails that isn't responding

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem on OSX 10.7, Rails 3.1.0, Ruby 1.9.2-p290

I just set up a pretty blank app to find out why I cant get it to work. I don't get any error messages but nothing is appearing. I don't know what to fix.

Here's what I have:

```
 <head>
  <title>Usewith</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

ItemsController

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json

  autocomplete :category, :name
```

Routes.rb

```
Usewith::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :items do
    get :autocomplete_category_name, :on => :collection
  end

  resources :categories
```

items/_form.html.erb

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :category_name, autocomplete_category_name_items_path %>
  </div>
```

Item model contains category_id:integer, category_name:string

Any help on where to start looking?

EDIT
I receive this error in Chrome console

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method > 'autocomplete'
>    jQuery.railsAutocomplete.fn.extend.init        autocomplete-rails.js:53
>    jQuery.railsAutocomplete                       autocomplete-rails.js:35
>    jQuery.fn.railsAutocomplete                    autocomplete-rails.js:28
>    liveHandlerjquery.js:3689 jQuery.event.handle  jquery.js:2966
>    jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle   jquery.js:2600
>    jQuery.event.triggerjquery.js:2894 handler     jquery.js:3420

autocomplete-rails.js:53

```
$(e).autocomplete({
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

silly answer but I realised I need to add in

> //= require jquery-ui

to the new application.js

and also

> <%= stylesheet_link_tag
>   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
>   %>

to application.html.erb

Answer (score 2):

I've never used jquery autocomplete but anytime I'm debugging jquery/javascript I use Chrome and the developer tools. The shortcut to bring it up is alt-cmd-I from Chrome

From there you can look at the "Network" tab to see if any requests are being made, even xhr requests. Clicking on a request will show the headers, content, cookies, etc. I'd say that's a good place to start.

If you use Firefox then you can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), basically the same thing.

Btw, as I was typing up this answer I saw SO get the following response :) Apparently for autosaving answer drafts.

```
{"message":"0","draftSaved":true,"disableEditor":false}
```